# Random restart around 12:30 am

Tags: windows-7, shutdown

I just built myself a new computer. I usually leave it on when I go to sleep, and keep uTorrent on to avoid automatic logout from inactivity. After running normal for like two weeks, the windows machine restarted itself at around 12:29am yesterday, and 12:30am today. The thing is I was not at the computer when this happens, just found that in the event viewer.

*"The previous system shutdown at 12:29:51 AM on ‎8/‎16/‎2013 was unexpected."*

*"The previous system shutdown at 12:30:17 AM on ‎8/‎17/‎2013 was unexpected."*

What should be noted are:

1. These are the only two random shutdown/restart during these two weeks, and they happened about the same time in a day.
2. The computer's running at around 40C when load is low, seems unlikely to be a temp issue.
3. There's logon activity at exactly 12am in the log, but I suspect that's just system at work.
4. Computer specs are i7-4770, MSI Hawk 7870 2G, Asus Maximus VI Hero, Samsung 840Pro 256G, WD 20EZRX, Seasonic X650. OS is Windows 7 SP1.

If there's other info one needs to know please comment.

Comment: @Ramhound a little harsh? Sheesh. Have you checked your Windows updates settings? It's a unlikely it would be 12:30 AM as the default is 3 AM, but perhaps Windows auto-updated and restarted.

Comment: @moses Yeah, I should mention that the updates option is "download, but let me choose when to install them". And when it's automatically installed and possibly restarted it should be 3:00am.

Comment: You could turn off Auto Restart after hardware errors to see if it's a BSOD. Other than that the only possibility that comes to mind is software updating itself and then restarting.